# Проблемы с переменной типа List

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Есть переменные типа `Form1.ValueSendMessages.ChatList[i]` при назначение её другой переменной `SetData.MainData` и, в дальнейшем, редактировании свойства `ModificationUserData` переменной `SetData.MainData`, происходит почему то замена этого свойства как в `Form1.ValueSendMessages.ChatList[i].ModificationUserData`, так и в `SetData.MainData.ModificationUserData`.

Почему так происходит?

```
ChatDataMessages SetData = new ChatDataMessages();
if (_Type == "Chat" || _Type == "GetUserData")
{
    SetData.MainData = Form1.ValueSendMessages.ChatList[_Index];
    SetData.MainData.TupeMessage = _Type;
    SetData.MainData.SourceIP = GetLocalIPAddress();
    //SetData.MainData.Message = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(TextMessage);
    if (TextMessage != null)
    {
        SetData.MainData.Message = new byte[TextMessage.Count()];
        SetData.MainData.Message = TextMessage;
    }
    SetData.MainData.LocalUser = Message.ChatSettingData.Name;
    SetData.MainData.LocalSID = Message.ChatSettingData.SID;
    SetData.MainData.ImagePath = string.Empty;
    SetData.MainData.Description = string.Empty;
    SetData.MainData.ModificationUserData = Message.ChatSettingData.ModificationUserData;

}
```

> Переменная Form1.ValueSendMessages.ChatList[i].ModificationUserData
>   переназначается ещё в одном месте, но там ошибки точно не может быть.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Очевидно в списке хранятся элементы ссылочного типа, и при присваивании его, вы не копируете объект, а лишь копируете ссылку на этот объект, таким образом после присваивания и `Form1.ValueSendMessages.ChatList[i]` и `SetData.MainData` - ссылаются на **один и тот же** объект.

Соответственно при изменении свойства этого объекта изменения будут заметны во всех переменных, которые на него ссылаются.

Comment: это из за ее статичности

Comment: @SergD29, не понял комментарий